# Python strings \u001 vs \x encode/decode

Tags: python

I have two types of Python strings that should be same but are in different encoding, and I am not sure how to convert them to the same type of encoding so I can compare them.

One of them is

```
\x0114.21.127.246\x01Mozilla
```

Other one is

```
\u0014.21.127.246\u001Mozilla
```

I understand \u001 is ^A and \x01 should be same but i am not sure if it is or not.

I have tried decoding them both to ascii, utf-8 etc but I am not successful so far.

Comment: What is the source of that strings? Usually it shouldn't be `\x01` or `\u001` in text but a binary `01` in the file.

Comment: The source is log lines.  Theres essentially ^As being read from a gzip file and I want to compare them from text in json file.

Comment: Those strings are not the same at all. Try comparing `len('\x0114')` and `len('\u0114')`.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I ended up converting them both to ascii and it worked.